# How do I hide/show tabBar when tapped using Swift in iOS8

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to mimic the UINavigationController's new `hidesBarsOnTap` with a tab bar. I have seen many answers to this that either point to setting the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` on a viewController which only hides it entirely and not when tapped.

```
 @IBAction func tapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    // what goes here to show/hide the tabBar ???


}
```

thanks in advance

EDIT: as per the suggestion below I tried

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
```

which does indeed hide the tabBar (toggles true/false on tap), but without animation. I will ask that as a separate question though.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

After much hunting and trying out various methods to gracefully hide/show the UITabBar using Swift I was able to take [this great solution by danh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935228/how-to-hide-tab-bar-with-animation-in-ios) and convert it to Swift:

```
func setTabBarVisible(visible: Bool, animated: Bool) {

    //* This cannot be called before viewDidLayoutSubviews(), because the frame is not set before this time

    // bail if the current state matches the desired state
    if (tabBarIsVisible() == visible) { return }

    // get a frame calculation ready
    let frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
    let height = frame?.size.height
    let offsetY = (visible ? -height! : height)

    // zero duration means no animation
    let duration: TimeInterval = (animated ? 0.3 : 0.0)

    //  animate the tabBar
    if frame != nil {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = frame!.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: offsetY!)
            return
        }
    }
}

func tabBarIsVisible() -> Bool {
    return (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.y)! < self.view.frame.maxY
}

// Call the function from tap gesture recognizer added to your view (or button)

@IBAction func tapped(_ sender: Any?) {
    setTabBarVisible(visible: !tabBarIsVisible(), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: this works great, but `tabBarIsVisible()` could be improved to handle cases like `UIViewController` embedded in `UINavigationController` like this: `func tabBarIsVisible() -> Bool {
        return self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.y < UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
    }`

I refactored  [this as class extension](https://gist.github.com/2bd8139c5f69b9434008.git)

Comment: url is depreciated :(

Comment: Bad approach, changing offset of UIView is never a good idea, causes issues when in-call status bar appears.

Comment: please edit this answer for swift 4 because it doesn't work in swift 4

Comment: I no longer code in Swift and won't be updating this answer to Swift 4 (maybe it remains useful to those not yet using Swift 4).Someone could add another answer with Swift 4 code as Kie and Allocate have done with their answers for 2.3 and 3.

Answer (score 26):

Loved Michael Campsall's answer. Here's the same code as extension, if somebody is interested:

**Swift 2.3**

```
extension UITabBarController {

    func setTabBarVisible(visible:Bool, animated:Bool) {

        // bail if the current state matches the desired state
        if (tabBarIsVisible() == visible) { return }

        // get a frame calculation ready
        let frame = self.tabBar.frame
        let height = frame.size.height
        let offsetY = (visible ? -height : height)

        // animate the tabBar
        UIView.animateWithDuration(animated ? 0.3 : 0.0) {
            self.tabBar.frame = CGRectOffset(frame, 0, offsetY)
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height + offsetY)
            self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    func tabBarIsVisible() ->Bool {
        return self.tabBar.frame.origin.y < CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame)
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
extension UIViewController {

    func setTabBarVisible(visible: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        //* This cannot be called before viewDidLayoutSubviews(), because the frame is not set before this time

        // bail if the current state matches the desired state
        if (isTabBarVisible == visible) { return }

        // get a frame calculation ready
        let frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
        let height = frame?.size.height
        let offsetY = (visible ? -height! : height)

        // zero duration means no animation
        let duration: TimeInterval = (animated ? 0.3 : 0.0)

        //  animate the tabBar
        if frame != nil {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
                self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = frame!.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: offsetY!)
                return
            }
        }
    }

    var isTabBarVisible: Bool {
        return (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.y ?? 0) < self.view.frame.maxY
    }
}
```

Comment: where do i call this?

Comment: In your ViewController with the TabBar. In the method you want to change the visibility of your tabbar in.

Comment: isTabBarVisible function does not work as expected on iPad. Refer to @Michael Campsall answer to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Bogy. It seems the added Swift 3 version from @Kof differs from the Swift 2.3 at some points. But Michael Campsall added a swift version already, so I think we're good here. Just take Micheal's. :)

Answer (score 13):

I had to adapt the accepted answer to this question a bit. It was hiding the bar but my view wasn't sizing itself appropriately so I was left with a space at the bottom.

The following code successfully animates the hiding of the tab bar while resizing the view to avoid that issue.

**Updated for Swift 3 (now with less ugly code)**

```
func setTabBarVisible(visible: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    guard let frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame else { return }
    let height = frame.size.height
    let offsetY = (visible ? -height : height)
    let duration: TimeInterval = (animated ? 0.3 : 0.0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn,
                   animations: { [weak self] () -> Void in
                    guard let weakSelf = self else { return }
                    weakSelf.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: offsetY)
                    weakSelf.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: weakSelf.view.frame.width, height: weakSelf.view.frame.height + offsetY)
                    weakSelf.view.setNeedsDisplay()
                    weakSelf.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    setTabBarVisible(visible: !tabBarIsVisible(), animated: true)
}

func tabBarIsVisible() -> Bool {
    guard let tabBar = tabBarController?.tabBar else { return false }
    return tabBar.frame.origin.y < UIScreen.main.bounds.height
}
```

**Older Swift 2 Version**

```
func setTabBarVisible(visible: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    // hide tab bar
    let frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
    let height = frame?.size.height
    var offsetY = (visible ? -height! : height)
    println ("offsetY = \(offsetY)")

    // zero duration means no animation
    let duration:NSTimeInterval = (animated ? 0.3 : 0.0)

    // animate tabBar
    if frame != nil {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration) {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = CGRectOffset(frame!, 0, offsetY!)
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height + offsetY!)
            self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            return
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    setTabBarVisible(!tabBarIsVisible(), animated: true)
}

func tabBarIsVisible() -> Bool {
    return self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.y < UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
}
```

Comment: Upvoted this as the code in the animation closure is needed to do this properly. If you slide the tabBar down you need to slide the view above it down as well or you will have a gap where the tabBar was previously. Don't forget to update the tabBarIsVisible code as well as indicated

Comment: It doesn't draw the self.view to it full size like intended because it should set self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true and it will give you the actual full screen size but now you won't be able to animate the tab bar.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! I've called the function in `touchesBegan` so I could touch the screen to toggle ;)

Comment: The white space is still there

Answer (score 8):

You can just add this line to ViewDidLoad() in swift :

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
```

Answer (score 2):

I use tabBar.hidden = YES in ObjC to hide the tab bar in certain cases. I have not tried wiring it up to a tap event, though.

Comment: This does hide the tabBar, but without any animation. Not ideal,but it works. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Code is okay but when you use `presentViewController`, `tabBarIsVisible()` is not working. To keep `UITabBarController` always hidden use just this part:

```
extension UITabBarController {
    func setTabBarVisible(visible:Bool, animated:Bool) {
        let frame = self.tabBar.frame
        let height = frame.size.height
        let offsetY = (visible ? -height : height)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(animated ? 0.3 : 0.0) {
            self.tabBar.frame = CGRectOffset(frame, 0, offsetY)
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height + offsetY)
            self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version:

```
func setTabBarVisible(visible:Bool, animated:Bool) {

    //* This cannot be called before viewDidLayoutSubviews(), because the frame is not set before this time

    // bail if the current state matches the desired state
    if (tabBarIsVisible() == visible) { return }

    // get a frame calculation ready
    let frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
    let height = frame?.size.height
    let offsetY = (visible ? -height! : height)

    // zero duration means no animation
    let duration:TimeInterval = (animated ? 0.3 : 0.0)

    //  animate the tabBar
    if frame != nil {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {

            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: offsetY!))!
            return
        }
    }
}

func tabBarIsVisible() ->Bool {
    return (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.y)! < self.view.frame.midY
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

To hide

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
   }
```

To show again

```
   override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 4**, and animating + hiding by **placing tabBar outside the view**:

```swift
if let tabBar = tabBarController?.tabBar,
   let y = tabBar.frame.origin.y + tabBar.frame.height {
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
     tabBar.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: tabBar.frame.origin.x, y: y), size: tabBar.frame.size)
   }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

To make the animations work with `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true` just do this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
})
```

Other than the other solution this will also work nicely with autolayout.

Comment: Have you tried this piece of code...? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: It's pasted directly from my project into Stackoverflow. Did you put it into your `@IBAction func tapped(sender: AnyObject)` function?
Did you attach a debugger yet and see if your app stops inside the `animateWithDuration` block?

Comment: The code-block is meant to be added to a controller that is part of a tabBarController.

Comment: I'm not stupid, I know how to do it man :) The code works in a matter that it hides the tab bar, but there is no animation for me. Which is understandable, because you want to animate changing a bool value. That's why it won't work.

Comment: animateWithDuration will have no effect since there is no change in the position of the tab bar frame. The only effect is that the tab tar will be gone.