# Why do navigation appear 20 pixels below status bar in the view?

Tags: ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIWebView on iPad size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194787/uiwebview-on-ipad-size)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINavigationController *naviController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];

    [self.view addSubview:naviController.view];

}
```

If I add navigation controller in the view, it appears about 20 pixels below status bar.
I want it appears just below status bar. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 480.0);
    viewController.view.frame = frame;
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I changed like above. It works. So far so good. If height was 460, there would have been blank line at the bottom. View's absolute coordinate is (0, 20). So, Navigation bar's coordinate is (0, 40). I think that was the problem. I will encounter another problem. 
Maybe there is way to change coordinate before displaying navigation view. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced this same issue.

This discussion was helpful: [UIWebView on iPad size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194787/uiwebview-on-ipad-size)

[Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34101/tony)'s answer helped me discover this trick:

```
naviController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out setting the view height fixes this problem. You can do it in the nib (xib) file or progammatically  when creating the view setting the view.frame = CGRect(0, 0, 320.0 460.0); or whatever it's supposed to be (in your case it looks like it should be 460.0 since you have the status bar on).

The main point is that if the view size is smaller than the height of the screen, there are no guarantees where your controls will show up.

Comment: viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 480.0); works before addSubview. I don't know it will have another problem. Thanks.