# Why do navigation appear 20 pixels below status bar in the view?

Tags: iphone

```
  (void)viewDidLoad {

     [super viewDidLoad];

     UINavigationController *naviController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];

     [self.view addSubview:naviController.view];
}
```

If I add navigation controller in the view, it appears about 20 pixels below status bar. I want it appears just below status bar. How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to release the navigation controller when you're done - you have a memory leak.

Comment: I know. But that is not the cause of this problem.

Comment: I know - I've answered the problem as well ;)

Comment: I'm having this problem with a MapView. Did you solve it?

Comment: see the first answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850705/why-do-navigation-appear-20-pixels-below-status-bar-in-the-view

Answer (score 0):

Just set the frame for naviController.view

```
naviController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare`UINavigationController` in the app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
```

[navController pushViewController:viewControllerOfYourExample animated:YES];

Comment: I think it works if I put the code in there. But I have put the code in the view. Because navigation have to appeare if I click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're adding your navigation bar at 0,0 then it looks like you're view isn't positioning correctly.

The easy fix is to move your bar to be at 0,-20

```
UINavigationController *naviController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
CGRect frame = [naviController frame];
frame.origin.y = -20;
[naviController setFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:naviController.view];
```

However, that's a hack.

Try something like this instead :

```
[[self view] setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
UINavigationController *naviController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
[naviController setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
[self.view addSubview:naviController.view];
```

That might work?

Comment: The First works. Second does not work. View seems to start from (0, 20). I don't understand why. Thank you.