# UISplitviewController and UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have a splitviewController for my iPad app that uses a uinavigationcontroller in its detail view (right view controller). Everything is hooked up in interface builder and after calling:

```
[self.window addSubview: splitViewCpntroller.view]
```

I get the left and right views to display.

The problem is, the navigation bar's y position in my right view is wrong and offset a bit (I think 20px) downwards so that there is a gap between the status bar and the right view's navigation bar.

I've spent the whole afternoon trying to figure out what's wrong but I didn't find anything. Since its all hooked up in IB I can't show you much code.

I'm sure it's a simple thing I'm missing and since it's IB it's probably hard for you to follow what exactly I was doing - but maybe one of you encountered this before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do navigation appear 20 pixels below status bar in the view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850705/why-do-navigation-appear-20-pixels-below-status-bar-in-the-view)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those questions that comes up pretty often, but for some reason it's hard to remember the answer. However, I think the root of your problem is that your view controller's view has a height that's too small -- try adding 20 pixels to the height, and also check its position.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Connecting things in IB is kind of hard to remember. Created everything programmatically and it works now. Sorry to bother. Cheers

Comment: @Mario You should accept this answer if you think it solves your problem.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe it didn't or I would have