# Full screen UIImage view

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiwindow

I have an application with a navigation bar and a tab bar.  A user can navigate to a view which displays images in a scroll view.  I'd like to have the same behavior as the iPhone photo app: Nav bar at the top, tool bar at the bottom, which will hide or show based upon a tap.

I'm moving my view to the window object in order to achieve full screen mode.  This works fine:

```
    myView = [self.view retain];
    self.view = nil;
    [window addSubview:myView];
```

But when I want to redisplay the Nav & tool bar, I run into a problem. The bars show fine, but the view is empty, and I can't seem to add any content to the view:

```
    [myView removeFromSuperview];
    self.view = myView;
```

I got a lot of good info from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110052/uiview-doesnt-resize-to-full-screen-when-hiding-the-nav-bar-tab-bar)

but can't quite get the right combination.

Answer (score 0):

By simply setting the controller's view, you aren't adding it as a subview to anything else, so it will never appear.

Moving views around like this can get a little tricky.  I recommend that you not move the view from one to the other, but instead have two UIViews.  Add second UIView to the window's subview and set it to hidden=YES initially.  When you want to show it, set the image for the UIImageView, and then set the hidden property to NO.

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with just using `setNavigationBarHidden: animated:` and `setToolbarHidden:animated:`?