# iOS - iPhone app consists of tab bars containing navigation bars.. overlaying a modal view makes area over tabset hard to hit

Tags: iphone, ios, modal-dialog, tabbar, viewcontroller

I have an iphone app consisting of a tabbar controller in the main.xib, where the tab bar controller contains navigation controllers, which are associated with corresponding view controllers.  I assume this is pretty standard.

If I present a modal view controllers view from a navigation controller contained in this hierarchy, the view owned by this view controller pops up as you would expect.  However, Ive noticed if I have controls (such as a button) at the very bottom of this 'modally presented' view it is rarely detecting taps.  It seems as though the tabset underneath is blocking the touches.  Note that when I present the modal view controllers view it fills the visible screen, it isn't sliding up from underneath the tab set.

I thought this tababar controller->navigation controller hierarchy was pretty standard, shouldn't I be able to present a modal view controller from a navigation controller in this set up without issue?  I have also tried to present the modal view controller from the tab bar controller, with the same effect.

How do I present a modal view controller in an app with the tabbar controller->navigation controller hierarchy such that the lowest portion of that view can detect touches?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the first answer by Harry, I believe this set-up is related to your situation. Post an update and let us know if this helps: [UIView doesn't resize to full screen when hiding the nav bar & tab bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110052/uiview-doesnt-resize-to-full-screen-when-hiding-the-nav-bar-tab-bar)

Also, what code are you using to present the modal view?